# DDD Изменение свойства сущности в зависимости от других сущностей

Tags: service, entity, ddd

**Исходные условия:**

Есть модель велосипеда. Она обладает рядом свойств:

- `Id` - уникальный идентификатор в базе данных;
- `Name` - имя
- `WheelsRadius` - радиус колес

Также есть 2 вспомогательных свойства:

- `Configured` - показатель сконфигурированности модели.
- `UsedByBike` - показатель того, что модель уже задействована при создании экземпляра велосипеда.

Модель считается сконфигурированной, если определены все свойства модели. В случае сконфигурированности модели, ее можно использовать для создания экземпляра `Bike`.
Если модель уже использована при создании экземпляра `Bike`, то ее свойство Радиус колес (`WheelsRadius`) изменить нельзя.
Все модели велосипедов хранятся в репозитории `BikeModelRepository`.

**Ситуация:**

При извлечении модели велосипеда из репозитория необходимо определять:

- используется ли модель на момент ее извлечения из хранилища.
- является ли модель сконфигурированной.

По идее для этого должны существовать отдельные службы службы (Service), по одной для каждой из представленных выше двух задач. В сущности BikeModel должны быть определены методы для проверки двух указанных выше требований. В каждый метод через аргумент внедряется соответствующий сервис проверки.

**Вопросы:**

1. Является ли корректным представленный подход с использованием свойств `Configured`, `UsedByBike` в плане ограничения корректировки свойств модели и использования самой модели при создании объекта `Bike`?
2. Если подход корректен, как лучше изменять свойства `Configured`, `UsedByBike`?

**Код модели велосипеда:**

```
public class BikeModel {
    BikeModelId Id { get; set; }

    public BikeModel(BikeModelId id, string name) {
        SetId(id);
        SetName(name);
        Configured = false;
        UsedByBike = false;
    }

    public bool Configured { get; private set; }
    public bool UsedByBike { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public double WheelsRadius { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        SetName(name);
    }

    public void ChangeWheelsRadius(double wheelsRadius) {
        if(UsedByBike) {
            throw new Exception("Модель велосипеда уже используется. Невозможно изменить радиус колес модели");
        }
        SetWheelsRadius(wheelsRadius);
    }

    protected void SetId(BikeModelId id) {
        if(id == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Некорректный идентификатор модели велосипеда");
        }
        Id = id;
    }

    protected void SetName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name == "") {
            throw new ArgumentException("Некорректное название модели");
        }
        Name = name;
    }

    protected void SetWheelsRadius(double wheelsRadius) {
        if(wheelsRadius <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Некорректный диаметр колес модели велосипеда");
        }
        WheelsRadius = wheelsRadius;
    }
}

public class BikeModelId {
    public int Id { get; }

    public BikeModelId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

**Код велосипеда:**

```
public class Bike {
    BikeId Id { get; set; }

    public Bike(BikeId id, string name, BikeModelId model) {
        SetId(id);
        SetName(name);
        SetModel(model);    
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public BikeModelId Model { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        SetName(name);
    }

    public void ChangeBikeModel(BikeModelId bikeModelId) {
        SetModel(bikeModelId);
    }

    protected void SetId(BikeId id) {
        if(id == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Некорректный идентификатор велосипеда");
        }
        Id = id;
    }

    protected void SetName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name == "") {
            throw new ArgumentException("Некорректное название велосипеда");
        }
        Name = name;
    }

    protected void SetModel(BikeModelId bikeModelId) {
        if(bikeModelId == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не определена модель велосипеда");
        }
        Model = bikeModelId;
    }
}

public class BikeId {
    public int Id { get; }

    public BikeId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще, ddd подразумевает, что объекты описывающие предметную область а) желательно иммутабельны, б) не знают про другие объекты и в) (главное!) реализуют ТОЛЬКО методы объекта предметной области. Т.е. объект собака умеет гавкать и кусаться, а не красить себе хвост в рыжий цвет. Для создания экземпляра Bike по вашим условиям следует использовать не кашу из методов модели/байка/etc, а, например, фабрику

Comment: Иммутабельность, если я правильно понимаю, относится к объекту-значению, например BikeModelId. 
Bike является сущностью, которая может изменяться. BikeModel также является сущностью. Кроме того, оба типа являются агрегатами. Один агрегат, в данном случае Bike, может ссылаться на другой при помощи идентификатора BikeModelId.
Методы, определенные в Bike предназначены для последующей модификации свойств, определенных в Bike. Так, например, пользователь программы со временем мог понять, что ошибся с моделью, заданной велосипеду.
Если я все правильно понял, противоречий DDD в данном примере нет.

Comment: Имхо Bike относится к Bike Model  а не наоборот. Тогда Bike Model ничего не должна знать про сами байки. А тут получается что на изменение (или создание) объекта класса байк, будет меняться сущность модели (выставляться свойства IsUsedByBike). Поэтому имхо,  rjhdby прав - тут для того чтобы задавать свойства объекта нужна фабрика, в которой уже можно проверить по базе есть ли байки которые используют эту модель.То есть IsUsedByBike имхо не нужно. Свойство Configured относится именно к сущности Bike Model и поэтому вполне может быть в Bike Model. Только должно быть расчётным

Comment: `public bool Configured { get { return this.Name != "" && this.WheelsRadius  >0 && this.Id > 0} }`

Comment: kban, огромное спасибо за ответ! Bike действительно относится к BikeModel. Подход такой: одна BikeModel -> много Bike. Просто Bike должен хранить в себе идентификатор BikeModel, чтобы можно было понять: какой он модели. Согласен с необходимостью использования фабрики, где можно было бы осуществить проверку использования модели.
Однако возник вопрос: фабрика используется для создания объекта. Как быть в случае необходимости изменения свойства уже созданного объекта? Ведь в таком случае также необходимо проверять факт использования модели.

Comment: В общем случая я бы создал сервис для действий с моделью байка. Чтото вроде 
`public class BikeModelSerivce{
public void UpdateWheelRadius(int modelId, int radius){
//// проверка на существование байков
var model = ///получить из бд по modelId
model.wheelRadius = radius;
// Созранить изменени в БД
}
}`
и в дальнейшем для изменения свойств байк модели использовал бы этот сервис.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Идея с сервисом мне нравится. Однако возник логичный вопрос: как быть в случае наличия множества параметров BikeModel, которые надо из формы сохранить за 1 раз. Понимаю, что можно создать соответствующие сервисы редактирования для каждого параметра. Но исходя из Вашего примера при обновлении каждого параметра будет осуществляться сохранение BikeModel, что приведет к лишней нагрузке на базу данных. Как быть в таком случае?